# Best way to handle tcp/udp reception.

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, udp

I'm writing a simple program that listen over the network for incoming tcp/udp packets and retrieve data from them. I need also to parse the packet header for getting the sequence number, etc. I'm running windows7 and VC++ 2010.

Obviously i need a packets generator and i want to use the loopback adress so the sender and receiver be on the same machine.

Since i'm beginner in c++ network programming, i need a little help to figure out how to proceed.

Should i build my own tcp/udp generator? if yes, must i use RAW sockets or a higher level api would be enough (possibility to get the ip header). If no, which generator should use?

What technologie should i use for the receiver? i was looking at the boost::asio and winsock2.h. But since i don't have so much time to discover both of them, Could somebody tell me what should i do.

Thank you in front for your help.

Best regards.

Comment: It's unclear whether you are writing a communications socket endpoint (such as a client or a server), or whether you are attempting to intercept communications that are happening between two other entities outside of your direct control. If you don't know much about what you are doing, use the Winsock interface because it's basically the same as the BSD socket interface, which you'll find almost everywhere.

Comment: @GregHewgill thank you for your reply. Actually it's socket endpoints. 
Considering using winsock, can i parse ip header? should i google "howto create RAW sockets" using it ?
MSDN says `Limitations on Raw Sockets : TCP data cannot be sent over raw sockets.` what that means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using winsock, then you don't have to worry about parsing the IP header at all. Winsock (well the OS really) does all that for you. There is no need to use raw sockets (I have done network programming for 20+ years and have never once needed to use a raw socket!).

So for a client, the functions you want are `socket`/`connect`/`send`/`recv`. For a server, `socket`/`bind`/`listen`/`accept`/`recv`/`send`.

Comment: Thank you for your these great advice.
What do you think about this code? Should i follow these steps? http://www.nullterminator.net/winsock.html

It's thread safe? Can i create 2 threads in the client one for udp packets and one for tcp? 

I'm a little bit confused and i hope you don't mind asking you few questions and benefit a little bit from your experience, sir.

Actually, i want a program that detects packets loss by controlling the sequence number in the header. Is it possible to create a server program that launch a certain number of messages (each message contains a custom structure)?

Comment: Will these messages wrapped in packets ordered by ip sequence number by using winsock?

Comment: Oh, detecting packet loss is a totally different thing. TCP automatically handles packet loss by retransmitting information when required, and the application never needs to know that retransmission is happening. With TCP, the bytes you put in one end either all come out at the other end in the same order, or there was an error (like a timeout) and the socket will be closed.

Comment: On the other hand, UDP does not offer retransmission or packet loss detection. That means you may be able to use UDP from your application to find out whether all the packets are reaching the receiver. Just put a number in the UDP packet, increment it each time you send, and look for the numbers in the receiver.

Comment: Thank you for making all that clear. To wrap up (excuse me for being such a noob) : 
I create a first program that sends to 127.0.0.1 N tcp packets and N' udp packets. Each packet contains a counter and myData. 

On the other hand, i create a second program that listen to the network and receive those packets and (just for udp) detects loss. Then i can grab all data and use it. 

Is that logically correct and possible to do with winsock.

Thank you again.

Comment: You will never get packet loss to 127.0.0.1 since that's your local machine. But aside from that, I'm unclear why you need to use both TCP and UDP. TCP is "immune" to packet loss (but too much and it will give up), so you would use that for most communication purposes. UDP may drop/duplicate/reorder packets, but UDP is often used for applications such as voice transmission where delays might be unacceptable. Normally you wouldn't use *both* TCP and UDP for the same information, there's no need.

Comment: I write that just to  learn the basics for an academic exercice. it's not a real world specs. So i wonder which the best approach to make that "weird" program in the most quickly way :)

Comment: Use Winsock, it provides everything you need.